# Paid LaTeX support for svmono+cleveref

Tags: discussion

Unfortunately, I expect that [Cleveref fails to pick up the footnote number when using svmono 5.6 class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562190/cleveref-fails-to-pick-up-the-footnote-number-when-using-svmono-5-6-class) is unlikely to get a valid answer “for free”.  Which company or which individuals would be appropriate points of contact to offer paid support for the question?

UPDATE: I am aware of Ulrike and a decent list of organizations listed under https://www.tug.org/consultants.html , but as the work can be done virtually anywhere on Earth, there is still the question whom to ask first.

Comment: You could ask someone listed here: https://www.tug.org/consultants.html

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thx! Well, I know there is this list, but I hoped that someone would point me to one or two organizations rather that to 10 of them plus, perhaps, Ulrike.

Comment: This is Ulrike's site: http://www.troubleshooting-tex.de/miscellaneous-en.php. Boris Veytsman is a TUG member. Massimiliano Dominici is member of the GuIT. They all are serious professionals.

Comment: In the meantime, Ulrike answered the original question.